# Modify attribute of component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have several radio buttons like the one you can see on the image, within a form in React. The user will be able to read a QR Code that will set a variable, and if that variable is equal to the number that is there in the picture (165...), then the radio button will change its attribute of **disabled** to **false** (*it will be from the beginning on true*). The thing is that I don't know how to take the exact radio button and make it unable so that the user can select it. I don't want to make a useState variable for each of the rows of the table because that would mean to have X variables. Any way to do this correctly?

[image]

Comment: One `useState` variable with array inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

> read a QR Code that will set a variable

From what I gather, you are already have a variable (probably a `useState`) that contains the code the user has scanned. During rendering, while iterating through the rows you can use that variable to set the `disabled` state for each individual row based on whether that row's code is the same as the scanned code. That way, there's no need to create a `useState` for each row in the table. Something like this:

```
const tableData = [
  12345,
  12346,
  12347,
  12348,
];

const App = () => {
  const [code, setCode] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <QrCodeReader onRead={setCode} />
      <Table>
        {tableData.map(rowCode => (
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="radio" disabled={rowCode !== code} />
            </td>
            <td>
              { rowCode }
            </td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </Table>
    </>
  );
};
```

Hope this helps, feel free to edit your question to clarify if this isn't what you meant.